# .net5 secrets.json not being used locally

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-5

I have a .net5 web app in which I am trying to add a secrets.json file so I have right clicked and created the file - in my project file I can see:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <UserSecretsId>1cb5a573-309c-4b03-b7e9-3c09794038bb</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The secrets.json file exists in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\1cb5a573-309c-4b03-b7e9-3c09794038bb:

```
{
  "GraphApi": {
    "ClientSecret": "secret-key"
  },
}
```

In my appsettings.json:

```
"GraphApi": {
  "TenantId": "tenant-id",
  "Scopes": ".default",
  "ClientId": "client-id",
  "ClientSecret": "From user secrets"
},
```

and in my program.cs:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
            {
                if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    // Use user secrets for local development
                    builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
                }
            });
```

however, it's not picking up my `ClientSecret` from the secrets.json - if I put the value in appsettings.json, it works just fine - is there anything else I need to do to make it work?

Comment: did you try exclude appsettings.json  from project ?

Comment: `CreateDefaultBuilder` should add UserSecrets automatically. You should check if your environment is set to `Development`. This will show you the current environment the app is running in. `var hostEnvironment = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>();
Console.WriteLine(hostEnvironment.EnvironmentName);`
Add it to where the Host gets built.

Comment: @SpaceBeeGaming I tried without that extra config but it made no difference and I'm definitely in the development as it's picking up settings from my development appsettings transforms

Comment: Then the next question is, how are you getting the config value?
This works in out of the box webapi: `_configuration.GetSection("Options").GetValue<string>("MyOption");` 
(`_configuration` is just `IConfiguration` through DI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a web.config that was added to the project and in that it wsa pointing the project to use the appsettings.development version which was overriding the secrets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net5.0\Project.WebApp.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="443" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Deleting this file and re-configuring the project to use iis express instead of iis fixed the issue